# IAM Role Conditions in AWS CDK Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am creating a new IAM Role custom policy, but it do a rollback with the reason: `MalformedPolicyDocument`

```py
myrole = iam.Role(self,config['CUSTOM_POLICY']['ROLE'],
    assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com'),
    role_name=config['CUSTOM_POLICY']['NAME']
)
myrole.add_to_policy(
    iam.PolicyStatement(
        effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        resources=['arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*'],
        actions=[
            's3:CreateBucket',
            's3:GetObject',
            's3:ListBucket',
            's3:PutObject'
        ],
        conditions=[
            {
                'aws:SourceIp':'192.10.10.10/32'
            }
        ]
    )
)
```

If I delete the conditions it works, what is the correct syntax considering conditionals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're leaving out the [condition operator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html). Are you looking for something like:

```py
conditions=[
    {
        "NotIpAddress": {
            "aws:SourceIp": ["192.10.10.10/32"]
        }
        
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer did not work for me, this is how it worked for python

```
iam.PolicyStatement(sid="AllowSendCommand",
                        effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                        actions=["ssm:SendCommand"],
                        resources=["arn:aws:ec2:" + Aws.REGION + ":" + Aws.ACCOUNT_ID + ":instance/*",
                                  "arn:aws:ssm:" + Aws.REGION + "::document/AWS-RunPowerShellScript"],
                        conditions={"StringEquals": 
                                     {"aws:ResourceTag/Name": [bastion_host_stack_name + "/BastionHostLaunchTemplate"]}})
```

Comment: Can confirm - conditions does not accept an array: TypeError: type of argument conditions must be one of (Mapping[str, Any], NoneType); got list instead. The above formatting works for me.